# Selenium Datepicker

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

Estoy practicando el web scraping con Selenium y BeautifulSoup y me he encontrado una página con un datepicker que no soy capaz de resolverlo.

La idea es muy simple, seleccionar el día que yo quiera y descargar el PDF correspondiente a dicho día:

La web es --> https://www.dipusevilla.es/bop/

Lo que llevo de código es lo siguiente:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.dipusevilla.es/bop/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="../chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
dias = soup.find('tbody').find_all('td')
for dia in dias:
    if dia['class'] != ['old','day'] and dia['class'] != ['new','day']:
        if dia.text == '14':
            print(dia)
```

He conseguido seleccionar el día que quiero, pero como lo he "buscado" con BeautifulSoup y no con Selenium no puedo hacer "click"

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Gracias de antemano!

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que entiendo es que quieres descargar el PDF, ¿no? sí es así no te hace falta Selenium. Y basándome en eso, te diré mi respuesta.

Te estás liando más de lo necesario.

Para el tema de `date-picker` o seleccionar una fecha de un formulario, normalmente (prácticamente siempre) hay un attributo dentro del mismo elemento o un input oculto que contiene la fecha con un formato, y cuando le das click al correspondiente botón, éste envía esa fecha en la petición.

En el caso de la web que pasas lo hace por javascript, con el evento `ondatechange` del datepicker.

Presiona `CTRL+U` para ver el código y busca el elemento `result-date-selected`, en este caso está en el mismo código HTML, pero podría ser que este en algún archivo JS (también podrías usar el inspector del navegador ir a la parte de event listener y ver los listener que tiene).

En este caso lo que hace es `get` a una `URL` enviando una fecha con formato `yyyy-mm-dd` (2021-07-14)

```
$.get("/system/modules/com.saga.sagasuite.theme.diputacion.sevilla.corporativo/handlers/search-bop-date.jsp", {date: "2021-07-14"} ).done(e => console.log(e))
```

Con esto, lo que puedes hacer es hacer la petición con python algo así como

```
import requests

r =requests.get('https://www.dipusevilla.es/system/modules/com.saga.sagasuite.theme.diputacion.sevilla.corporativo/handlers/search-bop-date.jsp?date=2021-07-14')
```

La respuesta de esto es un código HTML, solo tendrías que buscar `a.link-icon` de ésta respuesta y obtener el valor del `href` y descargar el PDF.

Comment: Ostras muchisimas gracias!!! Exactamente me fallaba lo que me has indicado de hacerle el ```get``` a la url con la fecha que quiero. Muchas gracias!!